# failed to build native modules on after node 16 upgrade and MacOS upgrade

Tags: python, node.js, v8, newrelic, node-gyp

I’ve upgrade to MacOS Monterey (12.3.1) and Node 16. Since then I’m failed running installation on some node modules due to `@newrelic/native-metrics` with the following error:

```
Error running install script for optional dependency: "/Users/zivl/github/data-science-client/serverless/ml-platform-services/node_modules/@newrelic/native-metrics: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node ./lib/pre-build.js install native_metrics
```

when digging in the logs, I’ve found it is using `node-gyp` and `python` so I thought maybe due to upgrading I will need to re-install them - so I did so. but reinstalling `node-gyp` / `python` (inc. switching multiple `python` versions (3.7, 3.9, 3.10) - still didn’t help.

I checked the node-gyp logs and saw the following:

```
node-pre-gyp http 404 https://github.com/hyj1991/v8-profiler-node8/releases/download/v6.3.0/profiler-v6.3.0-node-v93-darwin-x64.tar.gz

node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/hyj1991/v8-profiler-node8/releases/download/v6.3.0/profiler-v6.3.0-node-v93-darwin-x64.tar.gz

node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for v8-profiler-node8@6.3.0 and node@16.14.2 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
...
Failed to execute native-metrics install: No pre-built artifacts to download for your OS/architecture.
```

the `v8-profiler-node8` has no version for node 16.
I’ve trying looking for it online and so far didn’t find any solution :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, what helped me solve the issue is doing one of the following:

- install manually a global package of `node-gyp` and you should set the node to run that version only (read more about it online, I’ll try to find links but it is anywhere on the net).
- switch to `yarn 3` and `pnpm` and with those package managers the 3rd party scripts are not installed by default as in `npm`
- you can always use `npm install --ignore-scripts` but it sucks to have this flag everywhere…
- have two versions of python, `python2` and `python3` in `pypenv` global

I hoped this somehow helped you, other answers and solutions are more than welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to eliminate such problem completely.

If possible containerize your app, for example with Docker.
Unless you are writing the application specifically for the Mac OS.

https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/

It will make sure this does not happen ever again, may be better than one off solution to this :)

Comment: how containerizing my app would help in this case?
this problem blocks me from maintaining my local development environment

Comment: You can use docker for local development, I recommend it its really comfortable.
You can use mount volume option to mount your source code so you do not have to rebuild container each time you change code.

On top of that, unless you app its designed to run on MacOS Its is good to use docker with the arch that should be in production.

Comment: This really isn't an answer. I _wish_ I could containerize my app, but alas, the environment in which it's hosted does not allow the use of containers. So, is there someone who can answer the OP's question who understands that, while containerization is great and should be used if at all possible, that sometimes the app just needs to run natively on a VM/bare-metal? So how should one go about resolving the problem?